# Stop BPimage walker bot

Tags: spam

How can i block all bots except a few including BPImage walker...it is creating a huge amount of load on web site and consuming lots of bandwidth

Comment: **Make an effort** and supply a LOT more details. What web server are you using, what firewall(s) do you have, what behaviour do the bots exhibit, what user-agents to they have etc. etc. etc. `I want to do something, with something` **How can I write better questions on Server Fault** - http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault

Answer (score 2):

try robots.txt and see if they honor it.  If not try an apache rewrite rule.